# Russell, the Raging Bull mask

Tags: hotline-miami

In the PS3 version of Hotline Miami, how is the Raging Bull mask (Russell) obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This mask can be found at the end of Metro where you throw the briefcase into the dumpster directly to your left."

Source: http://hotline-miami.wikia.com/wiki/Russell_Mask

And here is some information about Metro.

http://hotline-miami.wikia.com/wiki/Metro

"Fourth section: Drop the case into the bin. When the bum comes simply rush him and knock him down. Pick up his bat and execute him with it." - This part seems relevant.

Hope that helps.